# SSIS passing parameter to WHERE clause hanging in Azure SQL DB

Tags: ssis, parameter-passing, azure-sql-database, oledb, etl

In SSIS I have the simple query OLE db source pulling from Azure SQL db and passing a date to a WHERE clause as:

[image]

with parameter:

[image]

It is at this step during execution that is hangs for 5+ min on the `Pre-Execute phase is beginning`, even if the datetime value being passed would return ~100 records.

However, if I hardcode the date to say '2019-09-01' it will execute in seconds...

How can I change things to make this run in a reasonable amount of time?

Comment: The "hanging on pre-execute' issue is a dreaded one that I'm not sure how to solve. But it would help if you explained how you are running the package - in SSDT? In Azure on-premise? In Azure Data Factory?

Comment: Not sure which environment you are running your task but I would check run-time variable value by debugging in SSDT to make sure it's passing the correct date format.. Just a thought!!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid What it ended up being, was SSIS was not using the index on the datestamp column, we added a query hint to force the usage of that specific index and now it flies

Answer (score 1):

[Since OLE DB source may have some issues detecting the parameter data ype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54289456/date-calculation-with-parameter-in-ssis-is-not-giving-the-correct-result/54297521#54297521), try adding a cast operation to the parameter:

```
Where [mnDateTimeStamp] >= CAST(? AS Date)
```

### Another Workaround

If it still not working, you can create a variable of type String. And define an expression to evaluate this variable. As example:

```
"SELECT * FROM Table Where [mnDateTimeStamp] >= '" + (DT_WSTR,50)@[User::LastRunDateTime] + "'"
```

Then from the OLE DB Source, use SQL Command from Variable option and select that variable.